# Maximum of list with expensive custom key function

Tags: java, collections, java-8, max, comparator

In Java to find the maximum element of a sequence you write:

```
GameState bestGs = Collections.max(ns,
        Comparator.comparing(e -> minimax(e)));
```

Here `minimax` is a function returning a number and `ns` is a collection. The code works, but the key function will be evaluated more than once for each element of the collection. How do I make it so that it is evaluated only once per element? In Python you would just write `max(seq, key = lambda e: minimax(e))`There must be something similar in Java? Don't tell me to write the forloop myself, it is the 21st century I shouldn't have to!

The explicit looping code goes like this:

```
GameState best = null;
// Doesn't matter what scalar type is used.
int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  
for (GameState n : ns) {
    int thisScore = minimax(n);
    if (thisScore > bestScore) {
        bestScore = thisScore;
        best = n;
    }
}
```

I want to write the above in a "functional" way in Java but also retain the high performance.

Comment: The result of `minimax()` could be stored with `e` as a key in a Map within the enclosing class.  Check the Map first to see if the value was already calculated.

Answer (score 2):

You could [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the `e -> minimax(e)` function:

```
public static <T, S> Function<T, S> memoize(Function<T, S> function) {
    Map<T, S> cache = new HashMap<>();
    return argument -> cache.computeIfAbsent(argument, function);
}
```

Then, simply use the memoized function:

```
GameState bestGs = Collections.max(ns,
    Comparator.comparing(memoize(e -> minimax(e))));
```

---

**EDIT:** This approach requires that `GameState` implements `hashCode` and `equals` *consistently*. These methods should also run very fast (which is the usual case).

---

**EDIT 2:** As M. Justin tells in the comments below, this solution is not thread-safe. If you are to use the memoized function from more than one thread, you should use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Comment: The performance penalty in the above solution is unfortunately very big.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner don't know if you realized, but another beauty of this the fact that `minimax` is not computed for duplicate keys

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I did measure it and got a 20% slowdown on real data. The handwritten loop only caches the running maximum, but your code stores one score for each GameState in the sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. But the jvm is `1.8.0_181` and the runtime flags `-XX:+UseSerialGC -Xss64m -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m` The length of the sequence is 4 - 16 items long.

Comment: `GameState` does not implement that.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist OK, that's the issue, then. In order to be used as the key of a map, it needs to implement those 2 operations. Otherwise, 2 different instances with the same data won't be considered to be equal. In other words, the cache is not working as a cache. If you could implement those 2 methods, you will see a great improvement in performance.

Comment: To address the caching argument, temporarily storing an additional `Integer` object for each of the (almost certainly) much larger `GameState` objects you already have in memory seems highly unlikely to have any noticeable impact in practice.

Comment: Just be aware that this implementation of `memoize` is not thread-safe.  If you ever switch from `Collections.max` to a parallel `max` implementation, you'd need to switch from `HashMap` to something that allows concurrent access, like `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @M.Justin On your first comment, I think it depends on how expensive `minimax` is in terms of time. It will always be much faster to return an `Integer` from a map than invoking an expensive method. Re your 2nd comment, you are absolutely right and I will add an edit. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @fps — I was more addressing the space usage issue brought up by "The handwritten loop only caches the running maximum, but your code stores one score for each GameState in the sequence." than the time issue. But you bring up a worthy point. Either way, it's highly unlikely that this will have noticeable impact in a realistic system either way, short of running in an actual real-time Java environment that's trying to avoid object creation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE;
import static java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;

...

var bestEntry = ns.stream()
                  .map(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(i, minimax(i)))
                  .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                  .orElse(new SimpleEntry<>(null, MIN_VALUE));

var bestGameState = bestEntry.getKey();
var bestScore = bestEntry.getValue();
```

After reducing, you will get an `Optional<Pair<GameState, Integer>>` which may contain the highest `minimax` result and a corresponding `GameState`. If there are no game states, we return the default entry `new SimpleEntry<>(null, MIN_VALUE)`.

Comment: I appreciate your downvote, but explain it, please :)

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your solution fullfills my critera but I'd be surprised if it is the best solution in Java.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist the best I could come up with... why don't you like it?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I think you need a small correction in your summary: "Smart people are nice. The world would be a better place if there **were** more meritocracies in it."

Comment: @AndrewTobilko it looks like you violate reduce here, you should return a new instance all the time, otherwise use `collect`

Comment: @Eugene I don't get it, what did you mean by "violate reduce"? how would you write this?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko `reduce` must return a new instance all the time, this is by specification; this means you need to return a new `Pair`

Comment: After the `.map()` step, can't you use `.max()` on the stream instead of `.reduce()`?

Comment: Where does the Pair class come from?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist, it is from the `javafx.util` package. Alternatively, you can use `Map.Entry` (and its implementation `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`) or write a custom class for wrapping 2 values

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist After the decoupling of JavaFX from JDK in the latest Java versions, it makes sense replace it with `Map.Entry`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Instead of `.reduce((a, b) -> a.getValue() >= b.getValue() ? a : b)`, you can use `.max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`

Comment: The [`Map.entry(k, v)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) method would be a little more idiomatic (and possibly slightly more performant) than `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` if you're using Java 9+.

Answer (score 0):

```
GameState max = ns.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(str -> minimax(str), Function.identity(), (gs1, gs2) -> gs1,
                         (Supplier<Map<Integer, GameState>>)() -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                 )).values().iterator().next();
```

Comment: `next()` without `hasNext()`?

Comment: Well, yes. It could be only if collections is empty. This should be checked before.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik that `Supplier` is not needed, inference would work just fine (unless you use Eclipse that has a problem with that); than you don't need `reverseOrder`  - just get the last entry; and since you do use a `TreeMap` might leverage it's methods like `lastXXX` and `firstXXX`; this could be done with `collectingAndThen` to make this a single pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about first computing `minimax` for each key first, store that in a `TreeMap` and just get the last entry once that is computed? of course you are paying for the extra storage.

```
int max = col.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> minimax(e),
                            Function.identity(),
                            (left, right) -> left,
                            TreeMap::new
                    ),
                    m -> m.lastEntry().getValue()));
```

This can be done even less verbose:

```
// Integer, Integer for simplicity
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<>();
col.forEach(x-> { 
            tm.putIfAbsent(minimax(x), x); 
            if(tm.size() > 1) {
                tm.remove(tm.firstKey()); 
            }
});
int max = m.lastEntry().getValue();
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner oh darn, right. But know that I look at your solution it makes perfect sense, it was 12PM when I posted this (lame excuse, I know)...